# C# MSTest "No test is available" via gitlab runner

Tags: mstest, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup some GitLab CI for C# .NET Framework 4.8 (windows) including MSTest project.
Using a windows runner locally on my workstation referencing msbuild and vstest.console within Visual Studio 2022.

Never having done stuff like this makes it very vague with lots of things I don't know yet.

So far so good. Compiling and deploy works, but it can't find any tests to run.
It returns:

```
$ & "$env:MSTEST_PATH" "dotnetframework-test\bin\Release\dotnetframework-test.dll"
...
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in C:\GitLab-Runner\...\dotnetframework-ci\dotnetframework-test\bin\Release\dotnetframework-test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using /TestAdapterPath command. Example  /TestAdapterPath:<pathToCustomAdapters>.
```

Some answers here say "just add NUnit adapters" but this is a MSTest project using framework, not Core. NUnit looks incompatible with Framework. I tried anyway, didn't work.
Much information is also very dated and VS 2022 seems to have changed things...

My gitlab.ci.yml looks like this:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  tags: 
    - windows
  only:
    - branches
  script:
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore'  # restore Nuget dependencies
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release'  # build the project
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week  # save gitlab server space, we copy the files we need to deploy folder later on
    paths:
      - 'dotnetframework-ci\bin\Release\dotnetframework-ci.exe'  # saving exe to copy to deploy folder
      - 'dotnetframework-test\bin\Release\dotnetframework-test.dll'  # saving entire Test project so mstest can run tests

test_job:
  stage: test
  tags: 
    - windows
  only:
    - branches
  script:
    - '& "$env:MSTEST_PATH" "dotnetframework-test\bin\Release\dotnetframework-test.dll"'  # running mstest tests
  artifacts:
    when: always  # save test results even when the task fails
    expire_in: 1 week  # save gitlab server space, we copy the files we need to deploy folder later on
    paths:
      - '.\TestResult.xml'  
  dependencies:
    - build_job
```

I started using the C# .NET Core template.
When I try to run the build and test steps via powershell myself it works fine. So something  is fishy...

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you include one of your test classes/methods? Are they properly decorated?

Comment: @TimothyG. no, there is nothing in there. They're just boilerplate. But I was able to fix this by also doing the nuget restore in the second job. Apparently it starts clean again?